# Why does my timestamp query not return values exactly on the hour?

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, sql-timestamp

I have a dataset of documents with associated publication dates (regular Postgres `TIMESTAMP`.
After noticing that some of these data points are for some reason invalid, I would like to remove all documents from a specific outlet that are published in the hour of 10-11 am, on two specific dates.

So far, I have come up with two different queries to do this, but they strangely return different results The first one returns all documents based on the simple `DATETIME` range query, and has 1603 results.

The second one queries only the days, and then all elements that have `DATE_PART('HOUR', published) = 10`, which should (in theory) return the exact same.

As the below query shows, though, there are two elements that are incidentally published *exactly* on the hour. Although they still have the same `DATE_PART` signature, they seemingly get ignored in the second query.

Can anyone tell me whether this is default behavior, or why this would return different answers?

```
postgres=# SELECT document_id, published, DATE_PART('HOUR', published) AS hour 
FROM documents 
WHERE (published >= '2016-08-18 10:00:00.000' AND published <= '2016-08-18 10:59:59.999')                                                         
OR (published >= '2016-08-28 10:00:00.000' AND published <= '2016-08-28 10:59:59.999') 
AND feedName = 'WP'
EXCEPT
SELECT document_id, published, DATE_PART('HOUR', published) AS hour 
FROM documents WHERE (to_char(published, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = '2016-08-18' 
OR to_char(published, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = '2016-08-28') 
AND feedName = 'WP' AND DATE_PART('HOUR', published) = 10;

 document_id |      published      | hour 
-------------+---------------------+------
       75676 | 2016-08-18 10:00:00 |   10
       76424 | 2016-08-18 10:00:00 |   10
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: `to_char(published, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = '2016-08-18'` can be simplified to `published::date = '2016-08-18'`

Comment: Can you include the `feedName` in your query results?

Comment: Works for me: https://rextester.com/DRXI78923

Comment: Wow, my bad. @404 pointed it towards the right direction: The feeds are actually different. Putting another set of bracket about the date ranges solves the problem.
I'll leave the question open for now, but I don't think others have much value in seeing this. Feel free to answer and I'll accept, though!

Comment: @dennlinger cool, you might as well put the answer yourself and accept it, since you figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be a missing set of brackets around the first query, where the two date ranges should have been connected with the `OR` operator inside a separate set of brackets, like so:

```
SELECT document_id, published, DATE_PART('HOUR', published) AS hour 
FROM documents 
WHERE ((published >= '2016-08-18 10:00:00.000' AND published <= '2016-08-18 10:59:59.999')                                                         
OR (published >= '2016-08-28 10:00:00.000' AND published <= '2016-08-28 10:59:59.999')) 
AND feedName = 'WP'
```